# Trying to solve the equation $2=9^n-28\cdot 3^{n+1}+245$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve this equation for $n$.
$$2=9^n-28\cdot 3^{n+1}+245$$

I don't even know if my path was correct when I split up $9^n$ into $3^{2n}$ and then continued with $2=3^{n}(3^{n}-28\cdot 3)+245$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Pleas share what you have tried so far. I imagine you are trying to solve for $n$?

Comment: **Hint:** Let $t=3^n$, and see what happens. :-$)$

Comment: Well yes I'm trying to solve for n. I don't even know if my path was correct when I split up 9^(n) into 3^(2n) and then continued with 2=3^(n)*(3^(n)-28*3)+245

Answer (score 2):

Set $x=3^n$ the equation becomes
$$x^2-84x+243=0$$
this quadratic has two integer solution $x=3=3^1$ or $x=81=3^4$ and $n=1$ or $n=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

We can turn this into a quadratic with a substitution. Let $u=3^n$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Set $m=3^n$ and you have $m^2=3^{2n}=9^n$. Then ou get a quadratical equation that you can solve for $m$. Finally, use the logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

Rewrite
$2=9^n-28\cdot 3^{n+1}+245$
as
$28\cdot 3^{n+1}-9^n=243$.

Then, factor 243 and see what that tells you.

Answer (score 0):

You first change $3^{n+1}$ to $3^n * 3$ and $3^2(n)$ to $3^n * 3^2$.
you then rearrange the equation to get:
$$2-245=3^n *(9-28(3))$$
divide both sides by the coefficient of $3^n$ and apply logs to both sides.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! See this post for a guide on how to format math: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference